# Finding closest id within span

Tags: jquery

I have two images within span. I need the value of id1 for each image-click.

```
<span class="deleteid">
  @Html.ActionLink(item.categoryModel.catName, "Show", new { id1=item.itemId})
  <img id="iconItemEdit" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/MyIcons/ee.png")" 
   style="width: 13px; height: 13px;"/>

  <img id= "iconDelete" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/MyIcons/delete.png")" 
    alt="delete" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;"/>
</span>
```

For first image I used

```
$('#iconItemEdit').live('click', function () {
    var it = $(this).prev().attr('id1');
```

It is working fine. I am having problem finding id for the second image. I tried using same code but it did not work.

```
$('#iconDelete').live('click', function () {
    var it = $(this).prev().attr('id1');
    alert(it);
```

is returning `undefined` instead.

Comment: Sometimes if there is space between the equals and the string quote, the browser will throw out the attribute.

Comment: try `var it = $(this).prev().attr('id');`

Comment: try this: `var it = $(this).siblings().attr('id1');`

Comment: What is the expected output for `attr('id1')`?

Comment: can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ link

Comment: but frankly speaking `attr('id')` is valid one but `.attr('id1')`...????

Comment: @NullPointer I trid using $(this).prev().attr('id'); but ir is returning name id of previous image.

Comment: @jai ur solution is working exactly fine .Actully my program required more than one id for different purpose.

Comment: great! good to go then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally clear what you want but try this:

```
$('#iconDelete').live('click', function () {
    var it = $(this).closest('span').find('a').attr('id1');
    alert(it);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you'll run across two issues here. First, you're getting the 'id1' attribute, instead of 'id'. This could be what you want, but 'id' is more common.

The original problem is likely simply that you're attempting to get the previous sibling of an element without a previous sibling. See this JSFiddle for an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Knjfh/

```
$(function(){
    var sID = $("#three").prev().attr("id");
    $("body").append("<p>The element previous to #three has the id '" + sID + "'</p>");
    sID = $("#one").prev().attr("id");
    $("body").append("<p>The element previous to #one has the id '" + sID + "'</p>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   var Id = $(this).find('span.deleteid').data('id');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$('#iconDelete').live('click', function () {
    var it = $(this).closest('span').attr('id1');
    alert(it);
});
```